# Elevator probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I found this in my math book. I have solved a), b) and e), but not the other ones. I only have a few thoughts about it.

A mathematical institute is situated in a highrise with two elevators. When working hours are over, everyone goes down to the exit, and the elevators often stop to let on more passengers. Sometimes two elevators go downwards almost at the same time, and Tom and Klara are discussing whether it is advantageous to take the last elevator (call it B) instead of the first (call it A) since there is a lower probability that B has to stop on the way down. We shall assume that the elevators are working in this way: The elevators go down in the original sequence until they get to a floor where someone is waiting. Then the first elevator stops and lets on waiting persons while the other elevator goas past it. The next time its B that stops while A goes past etc.

a) Show that A arrives in the ground floor first if there are people waiting in an even number of floors, while B arrives first if there are people waiting in an odd number of floors. (We assume that during this time there isn't anyone who is going off other places than the exit.)

My answer:
If the number of floors with people waiting is 2m, there are m pairs such that first B takes the lead but is caught up by A by the second element in each pair.

If the number of floors with people waiting is 2m+1, there are also m pairs such that B takes the lead but is caught up by a by the second element in the pair. Then B takes the lead again by an unmatched element and thus stays in lead.

b) We now assume that there are n floors between us and the exit (that is n places where people could be waiting). We also assume that the probability of anyone standing and waiting when the first elevator comes to a floor is p. Show that the probability that A gets down first is:

$P=\sum_{\{k\ is\ an\ even\ number\}}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

and the probability that B comes first is:

$Q=\sum_{\{k\ is\ an\ odd\ number\}}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

My answer:

We assume that for instance someone is waiting at the first two floors. The probability of someone waiting at a specific floor is p, and someone not waiting is (1-p). The probability for someone waiting at the first two floors is therefore $p^2*(1-p)^{n-2}$ The probability for a general number k is $p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$

All possible selections of two is

$\binom {n}{2}$

The number of all such combinations is

$\sum \binom{n}{k}$

The number of all even combinations is

$\sum_{\{k\ is\ even\}} \binom{n}{k}$

The number of all odd combinations is

$\sum_{\{k\ is\ odd\}} \binom{n}{k}$

The probability of each k must be multiplied by all possible combinations of k.

Because of that the probability that A gets down first is:

$P=\sum_{\{k\ is\ an\ even\ number\}}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

and the probability that B comes first is:

$Q=\sum_{\{k\ is\ an\ odd\ number\}}\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

c) Show that $P-Q=(1-2p)^n$

My thoughts: I know that all possible combinations equals 1, but can't get from there to $P-Q=(1-2p)^n$

d) Show that if n is an even number, there is always the biggest (or equal) probability that elevator A arrives first, but that if p is an odd number and $p \gt \frac{1}{2}$, then the most likely outcome is that elevator B comes first.

My thoughts: I guess you use $P-Q=(1-2p)^n$

e) If n=10 and p=3/4, what is the probability that elevator A comes first?

My answer:

$\sum_{\{k\ is\ an\ even\ number\}}^{10}\binom{10}{k}(\frac{3}{4})^k(1-\frac{3}{4})^{10-k}=\binom{10}{0}(\frac{3}{4})^0(1-\frac{3}{4})^{10}+
\binom{10}{2}(\frac{3}{4})^2(1-\frac{3}{4})^{8}+
\binom{10}{4}(\frac{3}{4})^4(1-\frac{3}{4})^{6}+
\binom{10}{6}(\frac{3}{4})^6(1-\frac{3}{4})^{4}+
\binom{10}{8}(\frac{3}{4})^8(1-\frac{3}{4})^{2}+
\binom{10}{10}(\frac{3}{4})^{10}(1-\frac{3}{4})^{0}$