# When can I expect my elevator to reach the ground floor, probabilistically speaking?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I live in a building with a ground floor (floor $0$) plus $n$ floors going up numbered from $1$ to $n$.

The elevator moves up and down at a normalized speed of $1$ floor/sec. When it stops at a floor and people get on/off, the load/unload takes exactly $k$ seconds, regardless of how many people get on/off.

I live on the top floor of my building (floor $n$). I get on my elevator and punch 'G' for the ground floor. The doors have closed and the elevator is starting downward. Suppose that at this instant in time there is nobody waiting on any lower floor to get on the elevator.

The elevator works like so:

- on every floor, people show up to use the elevator randomly; each floor is an independent Poissonian process with average rate $r$ people/sec.
- if, at the instant the elevator reaches a floor, there is one or more person(s) waiting on the floor, the elevator stops, picks them up (taking $k$ seconds), and proceeds; if there are no people waiting, the elevator passes without stopping
- every person who gets on the elevator is going to the ground floor, like me

Let $m$ be the number of floors the number of floors the elevator stops on, not including the ground floor.

My question is: *What is known about the discrete probability distribution, $p(m;n,r,k)$?*

---

Some notes/thoughts:

- intuitively, as $r \rightarrow 0$, the distribution will tend to a delta at $m = 0$; as $r \rightarrow \infty$, the distribution will tend to a delta at $m = n-1$
- my transit time to the ground floor is easily computed: $t = n + km$
- I suspect the distribution will have two peaks in many cases, particularly when $k$ is high and $r$ is low, based on the observation that the elevators will either sail quickly to the bottom (lucky case) or else get "trapped" in the higher floors picking people up while lower floors queue up with people in the meantime (unlucky case). In other words, I expect a polarization where the elevator ride will either take a very short or very long time, with not a lot of middle ground, when $k$ is large.

The problem is so basic that it would shock me if there wasn't a known solution to it--or to an equivalent problem. However, I don't know what the problem or the distribution are canonically called.

I'm asking this question out of pure mathematical curiosity. Although there's no shortage of elevator-related probability questions on math.SE, the following one doesn't appear to have been asked yet.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Funny that just three hours before your question, there was [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444061/elevator-probability) asking about elevators and probability, but with a very different problem statement